# How to use //? in VSC for JS programming

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

While following along a JS course, I saw the professor use //? to see the result of what he was typing. We all use VSC, if that's relevant. This is an example of how he uses it. However I don't get anything when I do it, nothing happens. Any clue what am I doing wrong or how do I get that in-screen print effect, withouth using console log?

Thanks

```
const removeFirstAndLast = arr => {
    if (arr.length >= 3) {
      return arr.slice(1, -1);
    } else {
      throw "You need at least three elements in the array";
    }
  };
  
  removeFirstAndLast([1, 2, 3, 4]); //?
  removeFirstAndLast(["<h1>", "Some content", "</h1>"]); //?
  removeFirstAndLast(["Some content", "</h1>"]); //?
```

Comment: Ask him what extensions he's added to his installation of VS Code.

Comment: There is [quokkajs](https://quokkajs.com/docs/index.html) which sounds like it does a _similar_ thing to what you're after.